# Mustache - Render Variable Value

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

I have two html pages `home` and `about` with a js variable defined on the top of page:

```
var pageAlias = 'home'; // on the home page
var pageAlias = 'about'; // on the about page
```

I want to pass that to mustache, and output values associated with that mustache key. Basically, the json has a list of all page headings, and I want to pull the page heading that matches the dynamic pageAlias. But not working for me. Here is what I have:

pageHeading.js (included in each html page):

```
// Page Heading
$.getJSON('page_heading.json', {}, function(templateData, textStatus, jqXHr) {
var templateHolder = $('#page_heading_template_holder');

// defined on every page as a var on the very top
// to pull in page title from Alias, so we can call it in mustache
var pageHeadingData = { "pageAlias" : pageAlias}

// merge pageAlias with json data
var templateData = $.extend(templateData, pageHeadingData);

$.get('page_heading.mustache.html', function(template, textStatus, jqXhr) {
    templateHolder.append(Mustache.render($(template).filter('#page_heading_template').html(), templateData));
    });
});
```

This allows us to render both `page_heading.json` and `page_heading.mustache.html` (mustache.html) is an external mustache file, being reused by both pages. Here we plugin the json into the mustache template, and we also add `var pageHeadingData = { "pageAlias" : pageAlias}` and merge it with the original loaded json.

page_heading.json (with the merged pageAlias shown)

```
{
    "pageHeading": {
        "home": {
            "title" : "Welcome to our website!"
        },
        "about": {
            "title" : "Where we came from."
        }
    },
    "pageAlias" : "home" //merged dynamically from .js to get pageAlias
}
```

The issue now is the mustache not being able to take the pageAlias value, home, find it under pageHeading, and render out the title:

page_heading.mustache.html (working)

```
// This works and pulls the title, but is not dynamic
<script id="page_heading_template" type="text/html">

    <div class="page-heading">
        {{#pageHeading.home}}
            <h1>{{{title}}}</h1>
        {{/pageHeading.home}}
    </div>

</script>
```

page_heading.mustache.html (not working - need help on this one)

```
// This does not work, pageAlias is taken literally and mustache looks for it
// in json not it's value, 'home', so the title is never returned
<script id="page_heading_template" type="text/html">

    <div class="page-heading">
        {{#pageHeading.pageAlias}}
            <h1>{{{title}}}</h1>
        {{/pageHeading.pageAlias}}
    </div>

</script>
```

How can I accomplish this, get the pageAlias dynamic value, to render out the corresponding pageHeading?

Comment: Why don't you just set the title on the JS side, rather than trying to do a convoluted lookup on the template side? Just set `{title: "whatever"}` and throw out `pageAlias`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are tryng to access is `pageHeading[pageAlias]`, which Mustache is simply not capable of. You should try an approach like this:

```
<script id="page_heading_template" type="text/html">
  <div class="page-heading">
     <h1>{{{title}}}</h1>
     <h2>{{{subtitle}}}</h1>
  <div>
</script>


{
  home: {title: 'Welcome...', subtitle: 'yay, you made it!'},
  about: {title: 'Where we came from', subtitle: 'and where we did not come from'}
}


var pageAlias = 'home';
// get the 'sub-object' instead of merging
// so that templateData looks like this:
// {title: 'Welcome to our website!', subttile: 'yay, you made it!'}
var templateData = pageHeading[pageAlias];
```

Comment: What if I had to add more data to the json to pull in mustache, like an `<h2>{{{subTitle}}}</h2>` after the `<h1>{{{title}}}</h1>` Meaning, `templateData` needs to be able to hold additional fields to render them in mustache, not just `title`. Not sure how to get it to work with multiple variables in mustache + the pageAlias technique I attempted.

Comment: I had to call it like this `var templateData = templateData.pageHeading[pageAlias];` that works fine and answers the question thank you!